# How do I Change the font of the text in a Button Control

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

I am using EPLUS to create a button and I would like to change the font and font size of the text in the button. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

button.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);

Comment: EPPLUS does not appear to support button.Font